# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

I have 2 tables, TableA and TableB

TableA Contains column LItems

TableB Contains column BItems

LItems and BItems both have various items of which only a couple are the same, I need to return only the matching items in LItems which are in BItems.

I have tried

SELECT 'LItems' from 'TableA' WHERE 'LItems' IN (SELECT 'BItems' FROM 'TableB')

but this says it was empty when I KNOW there are items of the same name in both.

I have also tried = instead of IN and this brings nothing back and tried INNER JOINS but this also brings nothing back.  When I run each select statement on its own and look through I can see that there should be results which are in both.

Comment: With the small exception that you are not using single quotes around your columns (I assume that was a typo or backticks), chances are your data isn't exactly the same with LItems and BItems...

Comment: Can you reproduce it at sqlfiddle.com?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you quoting things in your query? You should be able to use the following:

```
SELECT
  LItems
FROM
  TableA
WHERE
  LItems IN (SELECT BItems FROM TableB);
```

I would suggest an inner join instead but give this a try first. Also are you sure the names are exactly the same? You might try using lower() or another function to remove white space or capitalization differences.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response.  Unfortunately, this came back with zero results. I will try to find out about the lower() as im new to this and I think you maybe right.  I have looked at the results of each and they look to be the same.

Comment: I have just spotted white space.  I will let you know how I get on, thanks